# Exercise in Peano arithmetic and order relation

Tags: advice, peano-axioms

Show that if m<n. and k$\ne 0$ that km<kn

Working assumptions:

**6.22 Theorem** Let m $\leqslant$  n denote the fact that m ∈ n or m = n. Then the relation   is an order relation in ω.

**6.19 Theorem** (Associative Law for Multiplication). (mn)k = m(nk).

Attempted proof

If m<n;by 6.22 m=n or m$\in$n

If m=n we are done

If m$\in$n and k$\ne 0$ by 6.19 mk$\in$nk
Then if mk$\in$nk; mk$\subseteq$nk

Is it possible to do this theorem inductively on n?
Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Hint: induct on $k$. At some point you'll need to know that $<$ is compatible with addition. By this I mean

$$m < n \quad \& \quad a < b \implies m+a < n+b$$

If you've already proven this, great. If not, it is an easy induction on $a$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: But the problem deals with multiplication. If I do induction on k,do I chuck the base case

Comment: So my proof is wrong...

Comment: Yes. To induct on $k$ you must prove the claim for $k=0$ (which is easy, because we're assuming $k>1$, so the claim holds vacuously). Then you must prove the claim for $k+1$. You should use the definition of multiplication

Comment: And that proves it

Comment: Yes. That will prove it